# Explode array into table using snowflake

Tags: arrays, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to explode the array into different table in snowflake :
There is column in table which contains the array for example :

```
[
        {
          "id": "1ed464e0-8ed7-6d4a-a3e2-03c344c7e7cc",
          "replacementPath": "config.payment.tax.dealerStreet",
          "value": "18500 Studebaker Rd"
        },
        {
          "id": "1ed464e0-95d0-66a6-8397-1f755c73ec90",
          "replacementPath": "config.payment.tax.dealerZip",
          "value": "90703"
        },
        {
          "id": "1ed464e0-a0ef-6dac-86d2-db8601d77394",
          "replacementPath": "config.payment.tax.dealerState",
          "value": "CA"
        },
        {
          "id": "1ed4beb8-e6f8-6b32-b145-97a2afc00214",
          "replacementPath": "config.payment.stripeAccountId",
          "value": "acct_1LXvRUHulq12Rima"
        },
        {
          "id": "1ed464e0-9b2f-6908-a345-73121a466810",
          "replacementPath": "config.payment.tax.dealerCity",
          "value": "Cerritos"
        },
        {
          "id": "1ed464e0-890c-60aa-beeb-0f6afdeafe95",
          "replacementPath": "config.draas.sourcePartnerDealerId",
          "value": "135254"
        },
        {
          "id": "1ed489ef-df32-61bc-a696-df25ccf5493d",
          "replacementPath": "config.amp.ex1DealerId",
          "value": "20834"
        }
      ]
```

Need to explode the array into table :

```
id|replacementpath|value
```

if it was in json format I would have used flatten but I am not able to handle this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using FLATTEN:

```
CREATE TABLE t(col VARIANT) AS
SELECT '[{"id": "1ed464e0-8ed7-6d4a-a3e2-03c344c7e7cc",
          "replacementPath": "config.payment.tax.dealerStreet",
          "value": "18500 Studebaker Rd"
        }]';

SELECT 
    s.value:id::TEXT AS id
   ,s.value:replacementPath::TEXT AS replacementPath
   ,s.value:value::TEXT AS value
FROM t 
,LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT=>t.col) AS s;
```

Output:

| ID | REPLACEMENTPATH | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1ed464e0-8ed7-6d4a-a3e2-03c344c7e7cc | config.payment.tax.dealerStreet | 18500 Studebaker Rd |
| 1ed464e0-95d0-66a6-8397-1f755c73ec90 | config.payment.tax.dealerZip | 90703 |
| 1ed464e0-a0ef-6dac-86d2-db8601d77394 | config.payment.tax.dealerState | CA |
| 1ed4beb8-e6f8-6b32-b145-97a2afc00214 | config.payment.stripeAccountId | acct_1LXvRUHulq12Rima |
| 1ed464e0-9b2f-6908-a345-73121a466810 | config.payment.tax.dealerCity | Cerritos |
| 1ed464e0-890c-60aa-beeb-0f6afdeafe95 | config.draas.sourcePartnerDealerId | 135254 |
| 1ed489ef-df32-61bc-a696-df25ccf5493d | config.amp.ex1DealerId | 20834 |